# For loop in Matlab to assign elements in blocks

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

In Matlab I have 3x4 matrix `A:`

```
A= [67  10.9459999999963    10;
    86  10.8150000000023    9;
    67  10.8649999999980    10];
```

Now I want to have an array `B` such that the first `10` elements of `B` are `67`, the next `9` elements are `86`. Basically the third column of `A` determines each "block" of `67's` or `86's`. The blocks are not always of equal length.

```
B = [67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67]';
```

I have tried the following for loop:

```
B=zeros(sum(A(:,3)),1);
  for j=1:size(A,1) 
    for i=1:A(j,3)
        B(i,1)=A(j,1);
    end
  end
```

But every time the second for loop starts, `i` is reset to `1` rather than continuing on to the next block. But I'm unsure how to define the loop so it does that.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
A= [67  10.9459999999963    10;
    86  10.8150000000023    9;
    67  10.8649999999980    10];

b = [];
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    b = [b repmat(A(i,1), 1, A(i,3))];
end
```

Comment: cheers! Didn't even know repmat existed, but I guess you learn as you go along! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
B = repelem(A(:,1),A(:,3));
```

From the manual:

> `u = repelem(v,n)`, where `v` is a scalar or vector, returns a vector of
>   repeated elements of `v`.
>
> ...
>
> If `n` is a vector, then it must be the same length as `v`. Each element of `n` specifies the number of times to repeat the corresponding
>   element of `v`.

Comment: I'll note that `repelem` is a relatively new function introduced in R2015a.

Comment: @TroyHaskin yeah, thanks. I was so pre-occupied with making sure that this indeed works (since my MATLAB is old too:D) that I forgot to note that in the answer. I didn't realize though that it is *this* new.

Answer (score 0):

In orde to replace the loop you could just use `repmat()` function to generate a vector with n repetitions of a certain number which used in the right way can generate your desired result, something like this should do the trick:

```
result = [];
for j=1:size(A,1)
 result = [result;repmat(A(j,1), A(j,3), 1)];
end
```

For more information on `repmat()` refer to matlab manual.